# How do I perform aggregate query which returns 'grouping criteria' as a table header?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having `Project`, which has many `Task` objects are linked by `id` of Project , each `Task` has a status. I want to do an aggregate query that summarize all status of Tasks in Projects. I do a query

```
SELECT p.name, t.status, count (t.id) AS size FROM public.projects AS p 
JOIN public.tasks AS t ON p.id=t.project_id
GROUP BY p.name, t.status
```

But the result return each status of each project in one line.

```
name   status   size
-----  -------  -----
t1     foo      1
t1     bar      2
t2     foo      3
t2     bar      4
```

I want to to the result like this:

```
name   foo   bar
-----  ----  ----
t1     1     1
t2     3     4
```

How can I do that in SQL (I am using Postgres) ? Thanks.

Comment: look for `PIVOT` if you multiple values for `status`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT
    p.name,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t.status = 'foo' THEN t.id END) AS foo,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t.status = 'bar' THEN t.id END) AS bar
FROM public.projects AS p 
INNER JOIN public.tasks AS t
    ON p.id = t.project_id
GROUP BY
    p.name;
```